# Change position of Billing address in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I have to changed default billing address position which is coming under the payment information i need it after shipping method select , no after click on payment method.

I have tried lot of google and magneto docs but no luck with that.

[image]

Can any one please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: its all based on components and sort order for that , you need to work on move components into checkout_index_index.xml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

Please note that it might not be technically possible (or at least not very easy) to have a customer enter it's address after the payment / shipping methods. This is because Magento loads it's payment- and shipping methods according to the address the customer has chosen.

Also, manipulating the (default) checkout page in Magento 2 is a very comprehensive task on itself and requires deep knowledge on how the theming and layout of Magento 2 works.